# textfield to a label atumatically?

Tags: swift, label, textfield

Is there any way in which I can send information from a textfield to a label automatically while writing for example if I have 2 texfield and 1 label
one by name and the other by last name
that when writing a single letter or a name this automatically appears in the label
some way to do this with de button

-> `@IBAction func bt(_ sender: Any) { text =texfield!.text text = txfield!.text text.text = "\(textt!) \(texxt!)"`

Comment: this is a basic question you can find the answer by searching 'UITextField update callback' btw you should add a target for `.editingChanged` event for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this text change listener in your viewDidLoad method of View Controller.

```
yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

And add this function to your View Controller

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
     yourLabel.text = textField.text
}
```